# How to setup fusebox 5 framework with Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, frameworks, fusebox

I've got the fusebox framework files from https://github.com/fusebox-framework/Fusebox-ColdFusion. And I'm trying to make a fusebox framework setup with a simple coldfusion app in cf 2018. I followed the youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnBpKegsO3Q) to learn.

But Now I'm getting error like `Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface fusebox5.Application.`

In the downloaded folder I'm not having the fusebox5 folder. I'm not sure how to do this. If you have any documentation link please provide to me. I'm a new guy to the coldfusion technology. So, Please guide me to the right way to make the fusebox & CF setup.

Thanks friends!

Comment: OT: If you are new to ColdFusion, you should try FW/1 instead it is newer and better maintained. Fusebox hasn't been updated in years.

Comment: I would add ColdBox to that list as well.

Comment: Welcome to ColdFusion.  The FuseBox framework, as great as it was, has been dead for many years now and not maintained.  There are several modern frameworks you can choose from, a couple of which were mentioned above. Is Fusebox a hard requirement for you?

Comment: @JamesAMohler ColdBox > FW/1 Change my mind. :P

Comment: Friends, Much Thanks for your valuable suggestions and guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've got the solution for the fusebox5 setup with cf 2018. Should change the function name from `getCanonicalPath` to `getFBCanonicalPath`in the fusebox core files.

Following core files are need to be changed:

1. corefiles/PathUtil.cfc
2. corefiles/fuseboxPlugin.cfc
3. corefiles/fuseboxCircuit.cfc
4. corefiles/fuseboxApplication.cfc

After modified these files I can successfully run the code with fusebox5 framework.

I've got this idea from https://www.sidwing.com/2019/01/22/working-with-old-frameworks-fusebox-4-5/

This post is very helpful to me. It will help someone to make a setup.

Thank you so much, friends!